# javascript read through multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object in javascript that looks like this:

```
Cards:Object
     |->Pack:Object
            |->Spades:Array[60]
                     |-> 0: Object
                          |->  Card_img: "www.test1.com"
                               Card_type:"9"
                         1:
                          |-> Card_img:"www.test2.com"
                              Card_type:"8"
```

how can i loop through all the key->value properties in spades {0, 1, etc}? So it would return to me something like {card_img: www.test1.com, card_img: www.test2.com}

### my code:

```
Object.keys(cards).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(key); //gives Card how to drill down further?
});
```

if i do `Object.keys(cards.Packs).forEach(function (key)` I get `Object.keys called on non-object`

Comment: `for(i in Cards.Pack.Spades) { ... }`

Comment: `Spades` is an array, right?  Why wouldn't you just iterate through the array via numeric index?  `for (var i = 0; i < Cards.Pack.Spades.length; i++) { console.log(Cards.Pack.Spades[i]); }`

Comment: Note that on arrays there is a huge difference between `for ... in ...` and iterating via index (or using `Array.prototype.forEach()`): `for...in` does include non-numeric properties (like `.length`), while the other two don't.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get `cannot read property "Spades" of undefined`. If it's pertinent "cards" array has been Json.parsed.

Comment: That error means that `Cards.Pack` is `undefined` so naturally `Cards.Pack.Spades` doesn't work.  Can you show us the real javascript data structure (using javascript literal syntax), not this pseudo-code you've invented?  We can't help with the syntax if we don't know what the actual data structure is.

Comment: @jfriend00 you were right cards array was being passed in from a different function so I had to use, `for (var i = 0; i < cards.Cards.Pack.Spades.length; i++)` and it works, but how do i exclude the object prototype from my result?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what object prototype is in the array?

Answer (score -1):

You can't have an `object` with duplicate keys, but you can store each of the cards in an `array`.

```
// a dummy cards object
var cards = {
  pack: {
    spades: [
      { card_img: 'blah.png', card_type: '9' },
      { card_img: 'blah.png', card_type: '10' },
    ]
  }
};

// array to hold the spades
var spades = [];

// loop through each of the "pack" properties
for (i in cards.pack) {

  // loop through each of the cards of this suit
  for (j in cards.pack[i]) {
    spades.push(cards.pack[i][j]);
  }
}

// print out your cards
console.log(spades);
```

Comment: There are no duplicate keys in my object. I just was missing the outer container for my object.